# Reordering layers with Vue2Leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I am trying to change my layer order in Vue2Leaflet (so the top layer will be displayed when it is put as the first item in the array, but when I update the sort the array drawing the tile layers, the map does not reflect the change.

Can Vue2Leaflet sort layers?

Here is a fiddle showing the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/billyhunt/yjpmLre6/32/

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
  <button @click="reverse">Reverse Maps</button>
  <div>
    <b>Layer Order:</b>
  </div>
  <div v-for="tileProvider in tileProviders">
    {{tileProvider.name}}
  </div>
    <l-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
      <l-tile-layer
        v-for="tileProvider in tileProviders"
        :key="tileProvider.id"
        :name="tileProvider.name"
        :url="tileProvider.url"
        layer-type="base"/>
    </l-map>
  </div>
</body>
```

.vue

```
var { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker } = Vue2Leaflet;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom:13,
      center: L.latLng(47.413220, -1.219482),
      url:'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution:'&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      marker: L.latLng(47.413220, -1.219482),
      tileProviders: [
        {
            id: 1,
          name: 'Light',
          url: 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
          attribution: '&copy; <a href=\'http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\'>OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href=\'https://carto.com/attributions\'>CARTO</a>',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
          name: 'Dark',
          url: 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
          attribution: '&copy; <a href=\'http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\'>OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href=\'https://carto.com/attributions\'>CARTO</a>',
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    reverse: function() {
        this.tileProviders.reverse();
    },

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  The key from the object was setting the map layer order, not the array index.  If I change `:key="tileProvider.id"` to reference the array index, the layers reorder.

http://jsfiddle.net/billyhunt/xme403a9/7/

html

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
  <div>It would be great to be able to change the layer order by modifying the array.  I know I could us a control layer, but I have some other layers I want to control from another component.</div>
  <button @click="reverse">Reverse Maps</button>
  <div>
    <b>Layer Order:</b>
  </div>
  <div v-for="(tileProvider, index) in tileProviders">
    {{tileProvider.name}}
  </div>
    <l-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
      <l-tile-layer
        v-for="tileProvider in tileProviders"
        :key="index"
        :name="tileProvider.name"
        :url="tileProvider.url"
        layer-type="base"/>
    </l-map>
  </div>
</body>
```

js

```
var { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker } = Vue2Leaflet;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom:13,
      center: L.latLng(47.413220, -1.219482),
      url:'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution:'&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      marker: L.latLng(47.413220, -1.219482),
      tileProviders: [
        {
            id: 1,
          zIndex: 100,
          name: 'Light',
          url: 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
          attribution: '&copy; <a href=\'http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\'>OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href=\'https://carto.com/attributions\'>CARTO</a>',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
          zIndex: 101,
          name: 'Dark',
          url: 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
          attribution: '&copy; <a href=\'http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\'>OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href=\'https://carto.com/attributions\'>CARTO</a>',
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    reverse: function() {
      this.tileProviders.reverse();
    },

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My crystal ball tells me your changing the array manually you should use Vue's built-in set method like dis!

```
setLayerMethod (layer) {
  this.$set(this.layers, '0', layer)
}
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection Here is where it states vue has a limitation with arrays

Comment: I have messed with some of this, and still can't find the answer.  Here is a jsfiddle showing the problem.  http://jsfiddle.net/billyhunt/yjpmLre6/15/

Comment: I added a random key to the parent element. it doesn't work but i'm getting a different error.. maybe explore that? http://jsfiddle.net/jamesharrington/rodqx7fv/4/